# How to create a list from matching list of elements with a larger nested list

Tags: python-3.x, loops, nested-lists

I have a simple list:
`lst1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']`

I also have a nested list with the values above plus more:
`lst2 = [ ('a',[ 'aaa', 'bbb']), ('b',[ 'xxx', 'yyy']), ('c',['ww', 'mm', 'ii']), ('e',['rr', 'rr', 'tt'])]`

I have been trying to match all common elements in lst1 with the ones found in lst2 and create a new nested list with the common elements plus the nested values:

`lst3 = [('a',[ 'aaa', 'bbb']), ('b',[ 'xxx', 'yyy']), ('c',['ww', 'mm', 'ii'])]`

My code is as follow:

```
lst3 = [] 
for i in lst2:
    if i in lst1 and lst2[0]:
       lst3.append(i)
```

But lst3 ends up empty after running the loop.
Any tips would be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem with your code

You are checking `if i in lst1 and lst2[0]:` which never come `True`. because `('a',[ 'aaa', 'bbb'])` is not in `lst1`.

### Solution

```py
lst1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

lst2 = [ ('a',[ 'aaa', 'bbb']), ('b',[ 'xxx', 'yyy']), ('c',['ww', 'mm', 'ii']), ('e',['rr', 'rr', 'tt'])]


ans = []
for i in lst2:
    x = i[0]
    if x in lst1:
        ans.append(i)
       
       
print(ans)
```

#### Output

```sh
[('a', ['aaa', 'bbb']), ('b', ['xxx', 'yyy']), ('c', ['ww', 'mm', 'ii'])]
```

Comment: Not sure what I was thinking with my initial approach. Great help thank you.